# Available data interchange formats for android apps

Tags: dataformat, data-interchange

I am doing some analysis for an Android App (which basically collects data from simple forms) and am looking at data interchange formats that I could use. The app has to send data to a server over any available connection. I have looked at the following formats so far:

1. JSON (http://www.json.org/)
2. XML (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_whatis.asp)
3. Protocol Buffers (by Google)
4. EBML (Extensible Binary Markup Language)
5. CSV (Comma Separated Value)
6. OData (Open Data org)
7. SOAP
8. REST
9. Database Dumps (on Wikipedia)
10. CORBA (by OMG)
11. COM (by Microsoft)
12. HTML (Hypertext Markup Language)

I am inclined towards JSON, but was wondering if there is any standard/format I should be looking at and missed in this list.
P.S: I am allowed only two links... weird!

Comment: This question shows some research effort, it is useful but not so clear. Probably, as asked it is too general. Knowing a little more about the specific situation would have helped providing feedback.